# uninitialized constant Paperclip::Error with paperclip-ffmpeg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, ffmpeg, paperclip, paperclip-validation

I am using Paperclip , and paperclip-ffmpeg for processing uploads. Below is my code

class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base

```
 belongs_to :profile  
 has_attached_file :photo, :styles => {
      :mobile => {:geometry => "400x300", :format => 'mp4', :streaming => true}
  }, :processors => [:ffmpeg]


 validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png',  'image/gif', 'application/msword', 'application/pdf', 'video/x-flv']
```

end

when i upload image or video file then it is working properly. But when i upload PDF or doc

file, this error occurs.

```
       "uninitialized constant Paperclip::Error"
```

Any help??

Or How i can put if condition validation if upload file is PDF or Doc. Then i can skip this

below code. Because this is cause of error when file type is PDF or Doc.

```
        ":styles => {
      :mobile => {:geometry => "400x300", :format => 'mp4', :streaming => true}
  }, :processors => [:ffmpeg]"
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you got any logs for this?

Comment: Command :: ffmpeg -i '/tmp/stream20140507-5233-1qu3jll.doc' -y '/tmp/stream20140507-5233-1qu3jll20140507-5233-1nbuoe4.mp4'
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 211.7ms

NameError (uninitialized constant Paperclip::Error):
  app/controllers/job_seeker_controller.rb:126:in `new'
  app/controllers/job_seeker_controller.rb:126:in `new_resume'

Comment: @RichPeck above will work for you?

Comment: @RichPeck How can i put lambda condition with this? has_attached_file :photo, :styles => {
      :mobile => {:geometry => "400x300", :format => 'mp4', :streaming => true}
  }, :processors => [:ffmpeg]  #for skipping ffmpeg processor with doc file

Comment: Hmmmmmmmmm the person who'd know about this is [`@kirti thorat`](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1012097/kirti-thorat). I'll send her a message on LinkedIn to see if she knows what `Paperclip::Error` is

Comment: The problem seems to be that you're calling the `ffmpeg` processor, and it's raising an error, which cannot be processed as `Paperclip::error` cannot be found

Answer (score 1):

I have asked Kirti Thorat on LinkedIn for you - she may be better placed than me to deal with `Paperclip::Error` problem

---

> Or How i can put if condition validation if upload file is PDF or Doc

In terms of formatting your `has_attached_file` method to use a `lambda`, [here's what we've done before](https://github.com/joehilton/hpvideos/blob/master/app/models/attachment.rb):

```
has_attached_file :attachment,
     styles:        lambda { |a| a.instance.is_image? ? {:small => "x200>", :medium => "x300>", :large => "x400>"}  : {:thumb => { :geometry => "100x100#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10}, :medium => { :geometry => "300x300#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10}}},
     :processors => lambda { |a| a.is_video? ? [ :ffmpeg ] : [ :thumbnail ] }

def is_video?
 attachment.instance.attachment_content_type =~ %r(video)
end

def is_image?
 attachment.instance.attachment_content_type =~ %r(image)
end
```

This is relatively old code, so to keep you updated, `Paperclip 4.0` released a new media spoofing feature, which basically checks your file directly (instead of the extension) for its content type. Kirti knows a lot about that, so it will be best to wait for her answer

I could have a crack at it if you wanted me to